# How to find a file and copy its directory without copying the other files in that same directory?

Tags: files, find, cp, xargs, pdf

I have a lot of different folders with `pdf` files and other extensions. I want to copy all the `pdf` files to another destination. But if I do that with find like this:

`"${SEARCHDIR}" -iname "*.pdf" | xargs -d "\n" -I {} cp -r --backup=t {} "${OUTPUTFOLDER}/"`

I get all the `pdf` files in single destination and that is too messy for me. For that reason I want to copy the matching files including the parent directory but **WITHOUT** the non-matching files in that directory.

Input:

```
user/search/test/sub
user/search/test/sub2
user/search/test/file.pdf
user/search/test/file.doc
user/search/test2/sub
user/search/test2/sub2/file2.pdf
user/search/test2/file3.pdf
user/search/test2/file.doc
```

Should be copied as

```
/destination/test/file.pdf
/destination/sub2/file2.pdf
/destination/test2/file3.pdf
```

**EDIT:**
I don't want to copy the whole path. I don't want my output to be like this:

```
/destination/test/file.pdf
/destination/test2/sub2/file2.pdf
/destination/test2/file3.pdf
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, you could do:

```
set -o extendedglob
for file ( $SEARCHDIR/**/*.(#i)pdf(ND^/) ) {
  dest=$OUTPUTFOLDER/${file:t2}
  mkdir -p -- $dest:h && cp --backup=t -- $file $dest
}
```

Where `${file:t2}` gets you the two-component tail of the file, that is the file name and that of its parent directory. Then we create the `h`ead of that path as a directory and copy the file there.